# How to interact with self made OSX Kernel extensions?

Tags: c, macos, kernel, communication, inter-process-communicat

How to interact with self made OSX Kernel extensions?

I found the following Tutorial about creating an Extension: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptKEXT/kext_tutorial.html
Which works nicely but i couldn't find a way how to send commands to my extension.

It would be great if anyone could point me to an example:)

Or even post a minimal example :)

Why am i asking?

I'm aware that nearly everything is working inside the userspace. Since summer is coming and the temperature inside my room under the roof is getting higher it really hurts me to see my MacBook Air slowly boiling away. BUT than i stumbled upon this github.com/nanoant/DisableTurboBoost.kext. It seems to work. But there is no way to enable or disable on demand other than manually loading and unloading the kext. I would really like to have a litte app to send my extension the command to set or unset the Turbo Boost bit.

And after crawling the `http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf`  i found a lot of interesting functions to use. But i have no idea how to get the informations gathered out of my extension... Could you point me to an example? Or a useful book?

And since only a kext can use the kernel Framework i have no other choice to write directly to CPU registers... Or have i?? Could you point me to an example? Or a useful book?

Comment: What are you trying to do with a kernel extension?

Comment: I added what i want to the original post :)

Comment: This book has everything you need to know: http://www.amazon.com/Mac-OS-Internals-Systems-Approach/dp/0321278542

Comment: And this is a good accompaniment too: http://www.amazon.com/Mac-OS-iOS-Internals-Apples/dp/1118057651

Comment: Any hands on examples? Or something to read online?

Answer (score -1):

Generally, users seldom interact (knowingly) with kernel modules.

Consider general kernel modules such as a LAN driver, a disk driver, a file-system driver, etc.  In reality, users interact with these kernel extensions all the time; but they don't know it.

It is a very different environment than 'user-space'.  Generally, there is no stdin, stdout, stderr streams; where you can enter commands to your kernel extension from the keyboard, and see the result on a screen.

There are many ways that kernel extensions may use to interact with users (in userspace).  These include:

- System calls
- ioctl
- Virtual file systems
- Shared memory
- TCP socket or connection
- File-system events
- ...

It boils down to this:  The purpose of a kernel extension is to interact with the kernel, not to directly interact with users.

There are many ways for a kernel extension to interact with the kernel; but direct interaction with users is a foreign concept for a kernel extensions.

Comment: i'm aware that nearly everything is working inside the userspace. Since summer is coming and the temperature inside my room under the roof is getting higher it really hurts me to see my MacBook Air slowly boiling away. BUT than i stumbled upon this https://github.com/nanoant/DisableTurboBoost.kext. It seems to work. But there is no way to enable or disable on demand other than manually loading and unloading the kext. I would really like to have a litte app to send my extension the command to set or unset the Turbo Boost bit.

Comment: And after crawling the http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf i found a lot of interesting functions to use. But i have no idea how to get the informations gathered out of my extension... Could you point me to an example? Or a useful book?

Comment: And since only a kext can use the kernel Framework i have no other choice to write directly to CPU registers... Or have i?? Could you point me to an example? Or a useful book?